# How to specify to ignore a directory in .gitignore?

Tags: git

In a git repository, if I want to ignore a subdirectory (and therefore all the things under it) by adding it to `.gitignore`, is there any difference between

- `mysubdir`
- `mysubdir/`
- `mysubdir/*`

? They seem to work the same to me. Thanks.

Comment: `mysubir/` should be fine

Comment: With `mysubdir/` you can't re-include a file or directory in it via `!mysubdir/foo`. But you can with `mysubdir/*`.

Answer (score 1):

The "most correct" would be:

```
mysubdir/
```

The first in your list (`mysubdir`) will ignore directories and files by that name; likely not a problem, but potentially. The last only ignores the files under the directory, which has the same end result, because empty directories are ignored in Git by default.

If you look at the [gitignore files provided by GitHub](https://github.com/github/gitignore), you'll see they always ignore directories by the `directory/` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

There are some differences but they are subtle.

#### Without a trailing slash

Using:

```
mysubdir
```

ignores *any file or directory* named `mysubdir`.  If this is placed in the top level `.gitignore`, for instance, and you have directories A and B laid out as:

```
A/
    file
    mysubdir         <-- a file, not a directory!
B/
    file
    mysubdir/        <-- an actual directory
        file
```

then this `.gitignore` will ignore both `A/mysubdir` (a file) and `B/mysubdir` (a directory).  By ignoring the second, it cuts off all files *within* `B/mysubdir/` as well.

#### With a trailing slash

Using:

```
mysubdir/
```

ignores only *directories* named `mysubdir`.  In this case, `A/mysubdir` is *not* ignored, because it's a *file*.  But `B/mysubdir` is a directory, so it gets ignored.

#### With a trailing slash *and an asterisk*

Using:

```
mysubdir/*
```

tells Git that it should ignore all files and directories within `mysubdir`.  For this to happen, `mysubdir` must *be* a directory (if it's not, it cannot contain files and more directories).  So this seems, at first blush, the same as `mysubdir/`.  But it's not!

When you use `mysubdir/*`, you force Git to *read* the directory itself, to list out all the files within it.  It then checks each of these files against the patterns in the `.gitignore` file.  This means you can add, to the `.gitignore` file, an override:

```
!mysubdir/precious
```

This file or directory is *not* ignored, due to the leading `!` character.  But for Git to *find* the file, Git must *read the directory first*.  Had you listed `mysubdir/` instead of `mysubdir/*`, Git would have *not bothered to read the directory*, and would not discover the existence of `mysubdir/precious`.

Of course, forcing Git to read the directory has a (slight) penalty: Git must spend whatever time it takes to read that directory.  You should do this only if the penalty buys you something, such as *not* ignoring some file or subdirectory that is *within* that directory.